# error while generating two log.html files in robot framework by Rebot model

Tags: python, robotframework

I am trying to generate an error log html by “rebot” package of robot framework and its getting generated successfully.
But if I use the rebot function in my module then its affect default log and report html which gets generated after script execution.

```
[ ERROR ] Unexpected error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/utils/application.py", line 83, in _execute
    rc = self.main(arguments, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/run.py", line 445, in main
    result = suite.run(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/running/model.py", line 248, in run
    self.visit(runner)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/model/testsuite.py", line 161, in visit
    visitor.visit_suite(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/model/visitor.py", line 87, in visit_suite
    suite.tests.visit(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/model/itemlist.py", line 76, in visit
    item.visit(visitor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/model/testcase.py", line 74, in visit
    visitor.visit_test(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/running/runner.py", line 159, in visit_test
    self._output.end_test(ModelCombiner(test, result))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/output/output.py", line 59, in end_test
    LOGGER.end_test(test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/output/logger.py", line 183, in end_test
    logger.end_test(test)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/output/console/verbose.py", line 51, in end_test
    self._writer.status(test.status, clear=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/output/console/verbose.py", line 114, in status
    self._clear_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/output/console/verbose.py", line 124, in _clear_status
    self._write_info()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/output/console/verbose.py", line 90, in _write_info
    self._stdout.write(self._last_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/output/console/highlighting.py", line 51, in write
    self._write(console_encode(text, stream=self.stream))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/robot/utils/encoding.py", line 60, in console_encode
    return string.encode(encoding, errors).decode(encoding)
```

Comment: we need to see a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is rather clear. It looks like you're trying to encode a variable which contains a `None` instead of a string. You need to make sure that this variable always contains a string and handle cases where something else is inside. You can do it for example using the `try ... except` statement.

Comment: if I remove Rebot from my module then it works fine and default log.html will generate in robot-framework.

Comment: Problem only occurs when I am calling my defined method from robot script which contains Rebot function.

Comment: I'm sorry, but without seeing the actual code you use, I don't think I'll be able to help you more.